# Why am I being asked to explicitly initialize a member when I have already created a constructor to do that?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, hashtable

I'm trying to create a hashtable with chaining as the collision management method. I have a custom list to handle that. Here's the error I am running into:

> error: constructor for 'Node' must explicitly initialize the member 'content' which does not have a default constructor

Constructor

```
  Node(const Y &content) {
    this->content = content;
    this->next = nullptr;
    this->prev = nullptr;
  }
```

Comment: `this->content=content` is assignment not initialization.

Comment: Did you read the chapter in your C++ textbook that explains constructors' initialization sections, yet? What, specifically, in that chapter is unclear?

Comment: @Jason And you perform member initialization with which syntax? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> Why am I being asked to explicitly initialize a member when I have already created a constructor to do that?

Because `this->content = content;` is **assignment** and not **initialization**. Before entering the constructor body, the `content` data member(and also others) will be **default initialized**. But since there is no default ctor for `content`, we get the mentioned error.

---

To solve this you can use **member initializer list**.

```
Node(const Y &content): content(content), next(nullptr), previous(nullptr)
{

}
```